# Custom Object converter JavaFx FXML

Tags: java, javafx-8, converters, fxml, jpa-2.1

I am new to JavaFX 8 and I have been a JSF/Primefaces programmer for some time now. I am currently working on an JavaFX application with FXML and MVC pattern. I have a problem making converters of my JPA 2.1 entities in for the FXML GUI and how to use them. In JSF/Primefaces this is simple and straight forward and easy to integrate with a special tag for converters. I wonder if there is a similar solution for JavaFX with FXML. Please I need help.

Comment: What do you mean by "converters". What are you converting them to?

Comment: @James_D a Converter is an interface describing a Java class that can perform Object-to-String and String-to-Object conversions between model data objects and a String representation of those objects that is suitable for rendering.

Comment: Depending on what you're actually doing, this role is probably taken on by a cell. E.g. if you are displaying your entities in a `TableView`, each column defines a cell factory that returns a cell implementation. The cell defines how the property from the entity is rendered (it may be a simple text rendering, or something more complex). Some predefined cell implementations take an instance of a [`StringConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/StringConverter.html), which preforms simple object-String and String-object conversion.

Comment: If you can be more specific, you can probably get a more specific answer. As your question stands it's a bit too general to really lend itself to a complete answer. Presumably you have a list of entities that you get from a DAO of some kind and want to display that list somehow. So, how are you displaying them (`TableView`, `TreeView`, `ListView`, etc), and how do you want them rendered, etc?

Comment: Converter(customized) classes eases the display of custom classes in any component, be it textfield ot table column. That's how I have used them in most web frameworks. Usually the Converter class is written and then called where necessary. See [Custom converter in JSF 2.0](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/) to know how it is done in JSF. I wonder if there is a similar solution in JavaFx with FXML. Because I will need to be using these custom Classes often.

Comment: I just found your answer to: [javafx StringConverter Last Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466780/javafx-stringconverter-last-object) but will like to know how to convert my custom class objects for other component like text fields.

Comment: I don't think you can attain quite that level of flexibility. Bear in mind the context you are used to assumes you are converting to text (HTTP essentially only uses one data type, though frameworks try hard to conceal this fact...). In a desktop UI you might not even use text to render the property, see e.g. the example in the [`ListView` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm#CEGGEDBF).

Comment: For a `TextField`, you can set a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textFormatterProperty), which you can [instantiate with an instance of `StringConverter`...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#TextFormatter-javafx.util.StringConverter-). So probably creating `StringConverter` implementations is what you are looking for here.

Comment: Your last comment is somewhat helpful, I think the notion of object conversion in JavaFx is very specific. Thank you for your kind attension.

Answer (score 3):

The closest equivalent to what you are describing is probably the [`StringConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/StringConverter.html) class. All [built-in cell implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/scene/control/cell/package-summary.html) for virtualized controls (e.g. `ListView`, `TableView`, etc) can be configured with an appropriate instance of `StringConverter`. Additionally, for example, a `TextField` (or other text input control) can have a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textFormatterProperty) set on it, which in turn can be instantiated [specifying a `StringConverter` instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#TextFormatter-javafx.util.StringConverter-).

So if you have an entity class `MyEntity`, you can create a string converter:

```
public class MyEntityStringConverter extends StringConverter<MyEntity> {

    @Override
    public String toString(MyEntity myEntity) {
        return ... ;
    }

    @Override
    public MyEntity fromString(String textSpecification) {
        return ... ;
    }
}
```

which you will then be able to use in many parts of the API.

Comment: Thank you very much @James_D. This is what I wanted.